# java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.widget.ScrollView.addView

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error in Google Play Developer console. Stacktrace below is everything I have - nothing else is included. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.widget.ScrollView.addView (ScrollView.java:256)
  at android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView (BaseTransientBottomBar.java:436)
  at android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar$1.handleMessage (BaseTransientBottomBar.java:177)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5740)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:905)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

Comment: Do you working on anything related to ScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

GooglePlay console are ommiting the localizedMessage, but your error is ScrollView can only be host of one child.

You can fix this by using a single Layout (Like LinearLayout) inside the view and add the new childs to the Layout instead of the ScrollView.